# WEBMethods connection string is not working?

Tags: connection-string, webmethods

The following WEBMethods string is not connecting to the server on our companies network drive. I can take the string and place it in a web broswer and i will get a windows exploer screen but when run from WEBMethods the error is Access is denied.

Question: What is causing the access to be denied through WEBMethods? (I can access the file through internet explorer)

Connection String: (Names change to safe guard any information)
         //ServerName/DriveName/S/AB/P/T

Error:

```
     com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\espr1fs05
     \DSSXFER\SYSTEMS\ACCESS BACKUPS\Prod\Test\TBE-FILE02.txt (Access is denied)
```

New Code Added:

```
     System.out.println("outputDirectory --> " + outputDirectory);
     writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("doug.txt")));
```

I have the code in my Java service and would like to write to a network drive as a test.

```
     allowedWritePaths=//ESPR1FS05/DSSXFER/SYSTEMS/ACCESS BACKUPS/Prod/Test;
     allowedReadPaths=//ESPR1FS05/DSSXFER/SYSTEMS/ACCESS BACKUPS/Prod/Test;
     allowedDeletePaths=//ESPR1FS05/DSSXFER/SYSTEMS/ACCESS BACKUPS/Prod/Test;
```

The above is how the fileAccessControl.cnf file is configured and this is the same path that I put into the web service for the input file. When I test a write from Java it will work.

What could be wrong with the above write paths?

Error Statements:
             com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
             \ESPR1FS05\DSSXFER\SYSTEMS\ACCESS BACKUPS\Prod\Test\T.txt (Access is denied)

```
         com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
         \\ESPR1FS05\DSSXFER\SYSTEMS\ACCESS BACKUPS\Prod\Test\T.txt (Access is denied)
```

Comment: How are you accessing the file in WM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but did you try reloading the WMPublic package ? Maybe the changes you made to the fileAccessControl.cnf have not been loaded into memory.

Maybe it requires a webMethods server reboot.

Answer (score 1):

When you can not find a file in webMethods. There are maybe couple of reasons.

1. The file path is in the cache so it may different from what you think it is. Reloading the proper package will resolve it.
2. The webMethods flow don't have right permission to write to or read from the file. You can edit it in flow's properties window.
3. WebMethods server mount to the remote drive but don't have permission to read the file.

And I don't suggest directly process the remote file through webMethods. You should use FTP or SFTP to process the file in webMethods server and send it to remote drive.